# Якорные ссылки - скролл - JS

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, anchor

Коллеги, всем добрый день.

На сайте реализован скролл по якорным ссылкам. Метод нашел здесь же, на StackOverflow.
Все отлично работает. Но есть НО. У меня на странице header имеет свойство fixed.
Когда срабатывает скролл, часть блока, до которого он происходит, оказывается под header.
Помогите пожалуйста с решением. Думаю вычислять высоту header и добавлять ее
к верхней Y координате блока, к которому совершается скрол.

Спасибо

```
<aside class="service__aside aside">
  <nav class="aside__nav">
    <ol class="aside__nav-numlist">
      <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
        <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
        <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
        <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
          <ol class="aside__nav-numlist aside__inner-nav">
            <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
              <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
              <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="aside__nav-numitem">
              <a class="aside__nav-numlink" href="#"></a>
            </li>
          </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');

   for (let anchor of anchors) {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         let blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href').substr(1);

         document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start'
         });
      });
   };
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467997/14775762

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за наводку, но это не совсем, то что мне нужно. В моем случае header имеет разную высоту на разных разрешениях экрана. Так как я использую JS для скролла, то вычислять высоту header буду динамически. Вопрос как реализовать это в рамках скрипта, что я указал в вопросе. То есть вычислить высоту и добавить полученное значение к координате.

Comment: @ElJeko а что мешает прописать разный scroll-padding-top для разных разрешений экрана?

Comment: @andreymal хотелось бы обойтись чистым JS, не использую добавление классов к элементам.

Comment: @ElJeko а зачем для этого JS, если это делается на чистом CSS и даже без классов? Я как-то не очень понимаю вашу логику

Comment: @andreymal помимо логики есть сборка проекта, в условиях которой заложено использование JS для подобных манипуляций.

Comment: @ElJeko значит подобные ограничения нужно подробно описать в тексте вопроса, если самый очевидный ответ со scroll-padding-top не подходит из-за этих ограничений

Comment: (а лучше, конечно, подумать, а с какого перепуга эти ограничения взялись и как бы сделать так, чтобы от них избавиться)